# Showing error in different pane in ipad app

Tags: error-message, ipad, aesthetics

I have lot of panes (5 - 6) in a iPad app. Each pane depends on a different web service from different URLs.

What is the best way to show an error in one pane if the corresponding web service is not working? Just text in the middle showing the error makes that particular pane look very empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aesthetics aside (as what is and is not aesthetic is out of the ambit of this site), what is most important is that you **communicate to your users** what the problem is.

However don't communicate something that you aren't sure is true.  So saying "There is a problem with XYZ servers, please try again later" is not good unless you can tell that it is definitely a problem with their servers and not a problem with the users internet connection.

It would be better to say something like "There is a problem connecting to XYZ service. Please check that your internet connection is working, and try again later".